# Tikz zig-zag diagram with nodes of increasing size

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, tikz-chains

I am trying to achieve this:

[image: zig-zag diagram with larger nodes]

From this [tikz example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/assignment-structure/) I was able to get a straight line quite easily. I've tried adapting it using [this other tikz example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/labeled-chain/), but unfortunately it has not come out well - I can't get the nodes to align nicely. I've tried setting anchor=center, and similar, but they wont budge.

Minimal(ish) broken example:

[image: minimum broken example]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{minimal}

\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,%
    calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols,scopes}
\makeatletter % http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/labeled-chain/
\tikzset{joinl/.code=\tikzset{after node path={%
\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)%
edge[every joinl]#1(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
>=stealth',
  punktchainoff/.style={
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text width=6em,
    minimum height=10em,
    text centered},
  every join/.style={->},
}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, row sep=2em, column sep=2em, minimum
    height=30em, anchor=center] {
        \node [punktchainoff] (1) {\vspace{-1.6em}\begin{equation*}
            a
        \end{equation*}};
        &
        \node [punktchainoff] (2)
        {\vspace{-1.6em}\begin{equation*}\begin{array}{ccc}
            a & a \\
            a & a \\
            a & a \\
            a & a \\
            a & a \\
            a & a
        \end{array}\end{equation*}};
        &
        \node [punktchainoff] (3)
        {\vspace{-1.6em}\begin{equation*}\begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a
        \end{array}\end{equation*}};
        \\
        \node [punktchainoff] (5) {\vspace{-1.6em}\begin{equation*}
            b
        \end{equation*}};
        &
        \node [punktchainoff] (6)
        {\vspace{-1.6em}\begin{equation*}\begin{array}{ccc}
            b & b \\
            b & b \\
            b & b \\
            b & b \\
            b & b \\
            b & b
        \end{array}\end{equation*}};
        &
        \node [punktchainoff] (7)
        {\vspace{-1.6em}\begin{equation*}\begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b
        \end{array}\end{equation*}};
        %{$\ldots$}
    \\
    };
    { [start chain]
        \chainin(1)[join];
        \chainin(5)[join];
        \chainin(2)[join];
        \chainin(6)[join];
        \chainin(3)[join];
        \chainin(7)[join];
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The title should be "Ti*k*Zik-zak diagram ..." ;)

Comment: @Kpym hahaha :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would work with anchors and just draw the arrows in a loop because it is easier to implement an `\ifodd` there.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{minimal}

\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,%
    calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols,scopes}
\makeatletter % http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/labeled-chain/
\tikzset{joinl/.code=\tikzset{after node path={%
\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)%
edge[every joinl]#1(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
>=stealth',
  punktchainoff/.style={
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    draw=black, very thick,
%     text width=6em,
%     minimum height=10em,
    text centered},
  every join/.style={->},
}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[punktchainoff,anchor=south] (1) at (0,0)  {$a$};
\node[punktchainoff,anchor=north] (2) at (0,-1)  {$b$};
\node[punktchainoff,anchor=south] (3) at (1.5,0) {$\begin{matrix}
            a & a \\
            a & a \\
            a & a \\
            a & a \\
            a & a \\
            a & a \\
\end{matrix}$};
\node[punktchainoff,anchor=north] (4) at (1.5,-1) {$\begin{matrix}
            b & b \\
            b & b \\
            b & b \\
            b & b \\
            b & b \\
            b & b \\
\end{matrix}$};
\node[punktchainoff,anchor=south] (5) at (3,0) {$\begin{matrix}
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
\end{matrix}$};
\node[punktchainoff,anchor=north] (6) at (3,-1) {$\begin{matrix}
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
\end{matrix}$};
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {2,...,6}
{\ifodd\Y
\draw[->] (\Y.south) -- (\X.north);
\else
\draw[->] (\Y.north) -- (\X.south);
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: A version in which I kicked out all the unused libraries and use standalone instead of minimal.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
>=stealth',
  punktchainoff/.style={
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text centered},
%  every join/.style={->},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[punktchainoff,anchor=south] (1) at (0,0)  {$a$};
\node[punktchainoff,anchor=north] (2) at (0,-1)  {$b$};
\node[punktchainoff,anchor=south] (3) at (1.5,0) {$\begin{matrix}
            a & a \\
            a & a \\
            a & a \\
            a & a \\
            a & a \\
            a & a \\
\end{matrix}$};
\node[punktchainoff,anchor=north] (4) at (1.5,-1) {$\begin{matrix}
            b & b \\
            b & b \\
            b & b \\
            b & b \\
            b & b \\
            b & b \\
\end{matrix}$};
\node[punktchainoff,anchor=south] (5) at (4,0) {$\begin{matrix}
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
            a & a & a & a \\
\end{matrix}$};
\node[punktchainoff,anchor=north] (6) at (4,-1) {$\begin{matrix}
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
            b & b & b & b \\
\end{matrix}$};
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {2,...,6}
{\ifodd\Y
\draw[->] (\Y.south) -- (\X.north);
\else
\draw[->] (\Y.north) -- (\X.south);
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's beautiful, thanks :) I was beginning to think that maybe the matrix and chain libraries were not worth the hassle.

Answer (score 2):

One could solve this with the `chains` library but I also think, a TikZ matrix is more suited for it. Usually, I'd use directly TikZ-CD for this but this isn't to far fetched to just use a plain TikZ matrix of math nodes and a few edges.

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, matrix, quotes}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
  >=Stealth,
  punktchainoff/.style={
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text centered},
  C/.tip={Circle[length=+0pt +4]},
]
\matrix(m)[
  every outer matrix/.append style={inner sep=+0pt},
  matrix of math nodes, ampersand replacement=\&,
  row sep=3em, column sep=2em,
  nodes=punktchainoff,
  row 1/.append style={anchor=south},
  row 2/.append style={anchor=north}
  ]{
   \begin{array}{c} a \end{array}
\& \begin{array}{cc} a & a \\ a & a \end{array}
\& \begin{array}{ccc} a & a & a \\ a & a & a\\ a & a & a\end{array}
\& |[coordinate]| % fake target
\\
   \begin{array}{c} b \end{array}
\& \begin{array}{cc} b & b \\ b & b \end{array}
\& \begin{array}{ccc} b & b & b \\ b & b & a\\ b & b & b\end{array}
\\
}
[->, every edge quotes/.append style={inner sep=+.15em}]
  foreach[count=\d from 2] \c in {1, 2, 3}{
    (m-1-\c) edge["$f$"] (m-2-\c)
    ([xshift=1ex]m-2-\c.north)
    \ifnum\c<3
      edge["$g$"'] ([xshift=-1ex]m-1-\d.south)
    \else
      edge[-{>[sep=+0pt +6] . C[sep=+0pt +4] C[sep=+0pt +4] C}] ([xshift=-1ex]m-1-\d.south)
    \fi
  };
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]